# Titlesec with vertical spacing above and under part/section/subsection

Tags: spacing, titlesec

I created new titleformats for \part, \section and \subsection. Now I'm trying to insert a vertical space above and under each Title. For the \part it works just fine and for the other two the space above doesnt work, but the space under the text works.
Why is that?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titletoc}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{nameref}



\newcommand\content{%
    \titleformat{\part}
    [block]
    {\centering\Large\bfseries}
    {\MakeUppercase{Section}\thepart\linebreak}
    {1ex}
    {\MakeUppercase}

    \titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{2cm}{1cm}


    \titleformat{\section}
    [block]
    {\centering\Large\bfseries}
    {\MakeUppercase{Section} \thepart\thesection\linebreak}
    {1ex}
    {\MakeUppercase}

    \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2cm}{1cm}  



    \titleformat{\subsection}
    [block]
    {\centering\Large\bfseries}
    {\MakeUppercase{Section}\thepart\thesection\thesubsection\linebreak}
    {1ex}
    {\MakeUppercase}    

    \titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{2cm}{1cm}}




\newcommand\testtitle{%
    \titleformat{\section}
    [hang]
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
    {\thepart\thesection}
    {1ex}
    {\MakeUppercase}

    \titleformat{\subsection}
    [hang]
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
    {\thepart\thesubsection}
    {1ex}
    {\MakeUppercase}

    \titleformat{\subsubsection}
    [hang]
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
    {\thepart\thesubsubsection}
    {1ex}
    {\MakeUppercase}}


\begin{document}

    \content
    \part{aet}
        Lorem
    \newpage
    \section{ok}
        Lorem
    \newpage
    \subsection{lorem}
        Lorem


\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at --http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/layout/titlesec.pdf---page 21 onwards is informative

Comment: @jsbibra yes i saw that. but i still cant get it to work. there isnt really an example for this case